# Local Server with dynamic IP, DDNS and public Domain - Internal vs external traffic / routing

Tags: networking, ddns

I've just installed a Linux home server that operates as a private cloud with seafile. The server has a static IP in my LAN (ex. 192.168.1.7) but my ISP provides dynamic IP's, so I bought a DDNS service, added a domain (ex. example.com) and configured the ddns service plus some port forwarding on the router. All works perfectly but I'm unsure about one thing:

If a seafile client within the LAN up-/downloads something to the server via example.com, what route will be used for the data traffic? Is that DNS / Routing stuff smart enough to eventually match example.com to 192.168.1.7 within the local network? If this is not the case and manipulating hosts file on the clients is not an option (mobile devices that should be able to access the cloud from anywhere, or iOS devices), do I have to setup a local DNS Server to gain full LAN speed but retain the ability to be remote?

Answer (score 0):

Basically 'Yes'

You might be able to set your router to provide a DNS entry for your server to point 'blah.example.com' to your local servers local IP (192....)

If not, you'd want to run some kind of DNS server such as dnsmasq which allows you to easily add these kind of 'local' dns entries to your lan.

Once you've got this dns server up and running, you'd want to instruct your lan clients to use it, likely via the DHCP settings on your router. Again, if your router doesn't let you change these, you can run your own DHCP server too (just make sure to disable the one on the router!).

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure I really need this? Because if I do a 
tracert example.com
I get 1 hopp to my routers external IP. This would mean all data traffic stays inside the local network, right?